# Mathematica re-use the ColorFunction of another plot

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would very much appreciate your help on my problem. 
I would like to use the same color function that applies to the plot of data1 when plotting data2.
For example:

`data1 = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};`

`ListPointPlot3D[data1, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02], 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RGBColor[x, y, z]]]`

and next I wish to plot another data (of same dimensions) using the previous colors in the same exact order (there is an unknown function transforming data1 to data2):

`data2 = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}};`

`ListPointPlot3D[data2, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02], 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, fun[x, y, z]]]`

but for example a straightforward trial as follows will not work (although fun[] as such does work):

```
fun[r_, g_, b_] :=Table[RGBColor[data1[[i]]], {i, 
Length[data1]}][[Position[data2, {r, g, b}][[1, 1]]]]
```

Comment: Try asking over at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The gotcha in this is that `ListPointPlot3D` takes your integer data and converts to floats which it passes to your `ColorFunction`, so if you define your color function for discrete integers it fails to match the floats.  Try this.. (Your approach may work as well if you work with real data )

```
data1 = N@{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
cfun1[x_, y_, z_] := RGBColor[x, y, z]
ListPointPlot3D[data1, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02], 
 ColorFunction -> cfun1]

data2 = N@{{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}};
MapThread[ (cfun2[#2[[1]], #2[[2]], #2[[3]]] = cfun1 @@ #1) & , 
              {data1, data2}]
ListPointPlot3D[data2, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02], 
 ColorFunction -> cfun2]
```

A bit of an aside, but you likely would be better off working with graphics primitives, which would look something like this:

```
colors = cfun1 /@ data1;
Graphics3D@MapThread[ {#1, Point@#2} & , {colors, data1} ]
Graphics3D@MapThread[ {#1, Point@#2} & , {colors, data2} ]
```

Comment: The first example breaks down when more than 3 points are used. The second example works well with a modification:'cfun1[x : {_, _, _}] := RGBColor@x'

Comment: both approaches will have issues if `data1` and `data2` are not the same length.  You can use `data1[[;;Length@data2]]` for example to take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the colours from `data1` in the `PlotStyle` option of the `data2` plot. The list of directives in the `PlotStyle` refer to each data series so you have to make each point its own data series. I also take it that the values may not be between zero and one so rescale them for `data2`'s use of `RGBColor`.

```
ListPointPlot3D[data1, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02], 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RGBColor[x, y, z]]]
```

[image]

```
rs = MinMax /@ Transpose@data1;
ListPointPlot3D[List /@ data2,
 PlotStyle -> ({PointSize[0.02], RGBColor[Quiet@Thread[Rescale[#, rs]]]} & /@ data1)]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.